# Select2 in Knoucktout.js visible binding only shows but does not hide

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I use select 2 with knockout.js

I want to show and hide the control whether an item is selected. For this I bind the visible to `isSelected` observable property on the model.

Initially the select 2 is not visible. When the item becomes `isSelected = true` the box shows and *is* visible. So far everything is ok.

But when `isSelected` becomes false, I still can see the control. It doesn't disappear. Other controls on the same properties do work and hide and show correctly, so I'm sure that the property is set correctly.

Here my binding

```
<select class="input-xlarge" 
        data-bind="visible: isSelected(), options: stations(), 
                   optionsValue: 'Id', optionsText: 'Name',
                   value:StationdId(), selectedOptions:selectedStations, 
                   select2: { formatResult: $root.formatStationDropDown,
                              minimumInputLength: 3, quietMillis: 200, 
                              maximumSelectionSize: 1, allowClear:true }">
</select>
```

I assume that that has to do with the wrapper elements select2 is creating ?

As a workaround I can add a wrapping element and hide this, but for me this smells...

```
<div data-bind="visible: isSelected()">
   <select ....>
</div>
```

Is there any advice on how to do this right ?

And my bindinghandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(el, function () {
            $(el).select2('destroy');
        });

        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);
        $(el).select2(select2);
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

        if (typeof el !== 'undefined') {

            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

            if (allBindings.options.length > 0) {
                select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);

                $(el).select2(select2);

                var value = allBindings.value;
                $(el).select2("val", value);

            }
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: What does your `select2` binding handler look like?

Comment: i added the binding handler code in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the `visible` binding not beeing applied to the generated `select2` wrapper but to the original `<select>` element (which is rendered with a size=0 after select2 is generated).

You can use the containerless `if` binding:

```
<!-- ko if: isSelected -->
   <select ....>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: ok looks better then havinig a dummy div tag. i'll give it a t ry